# Getting com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException when trying to implement tabview

Tags: android, gradle, material-design, android-tabs

I am trying to implement tab view in my app. To do so I added the dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(':lib_MaterialDesign_EditText')
    compile project(':library_Android_Validator')
    compile project(':lib_MaterialDesign')

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.+'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

If I remove the line

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

build is successful, so I guess the problem is with that line. Can someone please guide me. Thanks in advance !!

The error I get in gradle console is

```
Execution failed for task ':app_Architecture_Retrofit:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```